Porting the RadioHead library for Heltec Cubecell AB01/02 (ASR650x + SX1262)
My question is regarding porting the RadioHead library.

This is the RadioHead Packet Radio library for embedded microprocessors. It provides a complete object-oriented library for sending and receiving packetized messages via a variety of common data radios and other transports on a range of embedded microprocessors.

I'm using it for Arduino-based devices + LoRa (RFM95 - clone of SX1276) like Moteino.
It works good for this type of devices.
I'm looking for a way to use it with Heltec CubeCell devices, which are based on theASR650x chip + SX1262 - like this.
I need to use CubeCell along with Moteino in the same "raw" LoRa network, so I need to use the same library on both devices, which implements device addressing.
The official Heltec library for Cubecell doesn't allow to have addressing and is mainly intended for use with LoRaWAN, which is not my case.
There is a Google group for communication about this library, but unfortunately my question is not very interesting for contributors.
The library works for another Heltec device, WiFi LoRa 32 (V3). Mainly because of the fact that this device is based on ESP32, which is supported by RadioHead.
But for Cubecell (ASR650x) it doesn't work. I can't even build a simple example.
There are a couple of topics about this and still no one has found a way to make it work.
I understand that Cubecell has its own SPI connection for SX1262, but it seems the issue is deeper than I can understand and fix it. It's all about support for the ASR650x chip.
Is there even some possibility that this library can be fixed to support CubeCell devices? How hard would it be?
Or maybe it will be better to somehow "copy" all RadioHead's stuff to the Heltec library?
I need advice from someone who knows CPP on a very good level.
Thank you..

